# Android Execute a method every X seconds with counter

Tags: android

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final int delay = 6000; //6 seconds
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) { //this counter shows 5 seconds
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                refreshtxt.setText("Updating in : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " sec" );
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                refreshtxt.setText(" Updating...  ");
                //i want to execute my method here
            }
        }.start();
        refreshtxt.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        handler.postDelayed( this, delay );
    }
}, delay );
```

First round, doesnt show the timer... but the succeeding round it is ok... Can anyone improve the codebase?  Ultimately I wanted to execute a method with a countdown timer every second...  the process doesn't stop as it is used to update recycler view display.  Please help.

Comment: does it have to run when you exit the application?

Comment: use a `TimerTask`

Comment: the process, will cycle, after the countdown, it executes a method, then repeat the countdown...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    int delay = 1000; //one sec

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //do process here
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay); // recall
        }
    }, delay);
```

Comment: I did, i just put a countdown timer inside so that i can see the countdown time before it executes my method.